# PHP - Find opening <p> tag before a specific string and add a class to it

Tags: php, string, str-replace, strpos

I have the following piece of text:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p><h1>standard dummy text</h1><p>ever since the 1500s</p>
<p>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
```

I need to add a class (`inline`) to the opening `<p>` tag before the occurence of the string `standard dummy text`. Or if easier it can use the h1 markup in `<h1>standard dummy text<h1>` if needed / easier? So that my text becomes:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p class="inline">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p><h1 class="inline">standard dummy text</h1> <p>ever since the 1500s</p>
<p class="inline">When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
```

The reason being is that I currently have to dynamically put the h1 markup within some text. This works however I need to add a custom `inline` class (which just sets the display to inline) to the paragraph beforehand so that the paragraph and header sit on the same line.

```
public static function markupH1TagWithinText($h1, $text)
    {
      $pos = strpos($text, $h1);
      if ($pos !== false) {
        $replacement = '</p><h1 class="inline">' . $h1 . '</h1><p class="inline">';

        return substr_replace($text, $replacement, $pos, strlen($h1));
      }
      
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: You check the `str_spilt` function.

Comment: You can't do this by only looking at the position where `</p><h1>standard dummy text</h1>` starts - you need to go back from there and find the first previous `<p>` in that direction as well, because that is one of the tags you need to replace. (And the whole thing would really rather be a job for a DOM parser, than string replacement or regular expressions.)

Comment: I'd use a DOM parser too. But I'm not sure to understand: why does the last `<p>` tag gets a `inline` CSS class ? Is adding the `<h1>` tag part of the job ? It's already present in the input text.

Comment: Do you need to add the `inline` class to every `<p>` after the affected `<h1>`? Or just the first one?

Comment: @EnricoDias just the first one after

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a DOM parser for that. PHP has the native [DOM extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) that is enabled by default.

Loop through all `<p>` elements and search for your string in the element's content. If you find it, split the element in 2 and insert the new `<h1>` in between. You can easily add your custom class in any element that you need.

Here's a working example:

```php
$html = <<< HTML
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<p>When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
HTML;

$text = 'standard dummy text';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$pNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach($pNodes as $node) {
    if (\stripos($node->nodeValue, $text) !== false) {
        list($valueBefore, $valueAfter) = \explode($text, $node->nodeValue, 2);

        $node->nodeValue = $valueBefore;
        $node->setAttribute('class', 'inline');

        $h1 = $dom->createElement('h1', $text);
        $h1->setAttribute('class', 'inline');
        $node->append($h1);

        $pAfter = $dom->createElement('p', $valueAfter);
        $pAfter->setAttribute('class', 'inline');
        $node->append($valueAfter);
        
        $node->nextElementSibling->setAttribute('class', 'inline');
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p class="inline">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's <h1 class="inline">standard dummy text</h1> ever since the 1500s</p>
<p class="inline">When an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
</body></html>
```